# Probability Question - three balls in a bag

Tags: probability, statistics

> A ball contains three balls, one blue, one red, and one yellow. Every
>   day, one ball is picked out of the bag and is then returned.
>
> 1) For how many days can you expect to not pick out a blue ball?
>
> 2) No blue balls have been drawn for one week. What is the probability
>   one will not be drawn for at least one more week?
>
> 3) How many times on average will a blue ball be drawn in December?
>
> 4) What is the probability a blue ball will be drawn 1 to 30 times in
>   that month?

Any help gratefully received... don't really get this :-( The only one I could try to get, but am not confident with, is the third one. If the chance of getting a blue ball is 1/3, and each drawing of a ball is independent, would it just be 31 (days in December) times 1/3 which would then be rounded to give 11 (rounded up) expected blue results?

Many thanks

Marc

Comment: If you think that rounding 31/3 produces 11, you have more basic problems :(

Comment: only thought it was more likely to be rounded up to the nearest integer.

Comment: Update... for the second one would it be (2/3)^7 because they are independent?

Comment: Expectation values are not rounded at all.

Comment: Concerning the independence, you are totally right.

Comment: Exercise 4 is not quite clear. Which one of the following is meant : The ball is not drawn 0 times and not 31 times. OR For every number l from 1 to 30, calculate the probability that the ball is drawn l times. I guess it is the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. What is the expected value of the number of days you can go without drawing a blue ball? Recall what expected value is: If values $x_1,x_2\ldots x_n$ occur with respective probabilities $p_1,p_2\ldots p_n$, the expected value is 
   $$x_1p_1+x_2p_2+\ldots+x_np_n=\sum_{j=0}^{n}x_jp_j$$
   So how does that help us here? Our $x$ values are clearly $1,2,3\ldots$, the number of days since which we have not picked a blue ball. What are our $p$ values? $p_1=2/3$, but what about $p_2$ etc. ?
2. The probability of drawing a blue ball is independent of other events. Thus the fact that a blue ball has not been drawn for a week is irrelevant towards the probability that a blue ball will continue to not be drawn. So this question becomes: What is the probability a blue ball will not be drawn for at least one week?
3. The answer is correct, the method a little non-rigorous. In other words, it completely works, but most likely requires justification. Try using the definition of average, and hopefully you'll get something involving the binomial theorem.
4. Consider the sample space. A blue ball can be drawn anywhere between $0$ and $31$ times, with probabilities $D_0\ldots D_{31}$. These probabilities must satisfy $D_0+\ldots+D_{31}=1$. We are trying to find $D_1+\ldots+D_{30}$. Thus our answer is equivalent to $1-D_0-D_{31}$, which is substantially easier to figure out.

Comment: Very nice solution! Short and straightforward and at the same time detailed and clear. +1

Comment: Agree - thanks very much for this as it was just enough to send me on my way!